# New line (\n) in Android XML. Android 4.1 SDK Compatibility issue?

Tags: android, xml, layout, newline

I faced this strange problem.

On my layout xml, I have a single `TextView`, and in it I have the following text:

"*Welcome to App.\n **etc***" , defined in `strings.xml`.

In a tablet running 4.0 displays the full string.

In a smartphone running 2.3.7 it displays just before the `\n`.

On previous apps I have created, `\n` worked okay.

Anybody faced something similar?

XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewWelcomeNotes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/msgWelcomeNotesHint"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/msgWelcomeNotes"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have different layout files for tablet/phone? It would be helpful if you post your XML. Also check if the textview is big enough to display multiple lines on the phone *(maybe it's smaller due to a smaller display?)*.

Comment: no, same layout. addded the xml! thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a weird bug of latest `ADT 20.0`, in `Eclipse Juno`.

I made a fresh install of Eclipse Juno, because i heavily loaded it with plugins,
and now `\n` appears okay, in the same apk, on 2.3 and 4.0+ Android Versions.

Also some other bugs, eg when creating new activity (`New->Other->Android Activity`), exist on this ADT.